# Saving the second td text from every tr

Tags: python, selenium

I have a table where I need to store all the invoice numbers in a list

[image]

Then I need to compare to a separate similar page.

I am not sure how to approach this, however this is what I have written so far but I am not sure if this is the right approach.

```
list = []
table_id = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'tblData')
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr") # get all of the rows in the table
for row in rows:
    # Get the columns (all the column 2)        
    col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1] #note: index start from 0, 1 is col 2
    list.append(col)
```

Comment: Has it worked for you so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use below line:

```
invoices = [td.text for td in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tblData']//tr[1]/td")]
```

Also note that you shouldn't use `list` as variable name as it is reserved name in `Python`